# Fill a column of a data-frame by matching the multilevel header of another data-frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, match

I have multilevel data-frame1:

```
Cstep                      step 0    step 1    step 2    step 3    step 4
D1      E1      S1       0.372621  0.211435  0.162299  0.149502  0.104143
                S2       0.104714  0.106229  0.119725  0.172926  0.496405
                S3       0.000000  0.270593  0.540627  0.188780  0.000000
                S4       0.144627  0.065209  0.060130  0.272958  0.457076
                Unknown  0.491222  0.188258  0.158279  0.162242  0.000000
        E2      S1       0.085831  0.328942  0.233738  0.242986  0.108503
                S2       0.336600  0.189705  0.314877  0.158818  0.000000
                S3       0.000000  0.448532  0.551468  0.000000  0.000000
                S4       0.000000  0.000000  0.248368  0.751632  0.000000
                Unknown  0.235332  0.371369  0.171224  0.222074  0.000000
D2      E1      S1       0.030488  0.272635  0.190137  0.153442  0.353298
                S2       0.000000  0.251659  0.309414  0.438927  0.000000
                S3       0.000000  0.381712  0.351985  0.266302  0.000000
                S4       0.827896  0.000000  0.172104  0.000000  0.000000
                Unknown  0.000000  0.189613  0.611961  0.198426  0.000000
        E2      S1       0.061281  0.223804  0.171979  0.271795  0.271140
                S2       0.124464  0.252529  0.388104  0.234903  0.000000
                S3       0.000000  0.045514  0.125909  0.190519  0.638058
                S4       0.000000  0.034438  0.000000  0.000000  0.965562
                Unknown  0.000000  0.239879  0.258064  0.502057  0.000000
```

I have another data-frame2:

```
         DT       RE       DS    
0        D1       E1       S1    
1        D1       E1       S2  
2        D2       E1       S2     
3        D2       E2       S3
```

I want to fill data-frame2 by matching the multilevel header values in data-frame1. Like this:

```
         DT       RE       DS    step 0    step 1    step 2    step 3    step 4
0        D1       E1       S1    0.372621  0.211435  0.162299  0.149502  0.104143
1        D1       E1       S2    0.104714  0.106229  0.119725  0.172926  0.496405
2        D2       E1       S2    0.000000  0.251659  0.309414  0.438927  0.000000 
3        D2       E2       S3    0.000000  0.045514  0.125909  0.190519  0.638058
```

Comment: Can you provide an easier way to create `df1`, maybe `df1.to_dict`?

Comment: If you reset_index() data-frame1 don't you get the desired output? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: 1) dataframe1.reset(index)
2) left join from dataframe2 to dataframe1 on DT, RE, DS

Answer (score 1):

Create a `MultiIndex` and `fillna`

```
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df2.T.values)
m = pd.DataFrame(index=m_idx, columns=df1.columns)

m.fillna(df1)
```

```
            step 0    step 1    step 2    step 3    step 4
D1 E1 S1  0.372621  0.211435  0.162299  0.149502  0.104143
      S2  0.104714  0.106229  0.119725  0.172926  0.496405
D2 E1 S2         0  0.251659  0.309414  0.438927         0
   E2 S3         0  0.045514  0.125909  0.190519  0.638058
```

---

If anyone else would like to chime in, here's an easy way to recreate the DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'step 0': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.372621, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.10471400000000002, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.144627, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.49122200000000005, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.08583099999999999, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.3366, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.235332, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.030488, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.827896, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.061280999999999995, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.124464, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0}, 'step 1': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.21143499999999998, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.10622899999999999, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.270593, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.065209, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.18825799999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.328942, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.18970499999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.448532, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.371369, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.272635, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.251659, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.381712, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.189613, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.223804, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.252529, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.045514, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.034437999999999996, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.239879}, 'step 2': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.162299, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.119725, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.5406270000000001, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.060129999999999996, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.158279, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.233738, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.314877, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.5514680000000001, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.24836799999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.171224, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.190137, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.30941399999999997, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.351985, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.172104, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.611961, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.171979, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.388104, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.125909, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.25806399999999996}, 'step 3': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.149502, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.172926, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.18878, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.272958, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.162242, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.242986, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.15881800000000001, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.751632, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.22207399999999997, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.153442, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.43892700000000007, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.266302, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.198426, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.271795, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.23490300000000003, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.190519, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.502057}, 'step 4': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.104143, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.49640500000000004, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.45707600000000004, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.108503, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.353298, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.27114, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.638058, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.965562, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DT': {0: 'D1', 1: 'D1', 2: 'D2', 3: 'D2'}, 'RE': {0: 'E1', 1: 'E1', 2: 'E1', 3: 'E2'}, 'DS': {0: 'S1', 1: 'S2', 2: 'S2', 3: 'S3'}})
```

Comment: I tried to recreate the data frame and tried then tried to code provided by you. It does not fill new data-frame m

Comment: Are you saving the result? Try `m = m.fillna(df1)`

Comment: I tried saving 'm = m.fillna(df1)' . It still does not fill the dataframe m. I have added the code as the answer. Please see that.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. The data frame  df2 changed it column order.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes columns of df2 change its order. Reorder them.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'step 0': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.372621, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.10471400000000002, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.144627, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.49122200000000005, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.08583099999999999, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.3366, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.235332, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.030488, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.827896, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.061280999999999995, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.124464, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0}, 'step 1': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.21143499999999998, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.10622899999999999, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.270593, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.065209, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.18825799999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.328942, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.18970499999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.448532, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.371369, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.272635, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.251659, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.381712, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.189613, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.223804, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.252529, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.045514, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.034437999999999996, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.239879}, 'step 2': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.162299, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.119725, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.5406270000000001, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.060129999999999996, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.158279, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.233738, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.314877, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.5514680000000001, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.24836799999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.171224, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.190137, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.30941399999999997, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.351985, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.172104, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.611961, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.171979, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.388104, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.125909, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.25806399999999996}, 'step 3': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.149502, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.172926, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.18878, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.272958, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.162242, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.242986, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.15881800000000001, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.751632, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.22207399999999997, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.153442, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.43892700000000007, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.266302, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.198426, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.271795, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.23490300000000003, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.190519, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.502057}, 'step 4': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.104143, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.49640500000000004, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.45707600000000004, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.108503, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.353298, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.27114, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.638058, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.965562, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DT':['D1','D1','D2','D2','D1','D2'], 'RE':['E1','E1','E1','E2','E1','E1'], 'DS':['S1','S2','S2','S3','S1','S2']})
df2 = df2[['DT', 'RE', 'DS']]
print(df1)
print(df2)
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df2.T.values)
m = pd.DataFrame(index=m_idx, columns=df1.columns)
m.update(df1)
print(m)
```